# JS text selection on Gmail

Tags: javascript, gmail, bookmarklet

I'm building a bookmarklet that takes the selected text and sends it back to my server where it is processed. It works on every site except Gmail. Anyone know how to get it to work on Gmail. Here is the code I'm using:

```
var selectedText = '';
if (window.getSelection) {
  selectedText = window.getSelection();
} else if (document.getSelection) {
  selectedText = document.getSelection();
} else if (document.selection) {
  selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
} else {
  selectedText = document.activeElement.contentWindow.getSelection();
};
```

Comment: I find it rather lame that whomever down-voted without commenting as to why. Good question Conor, and good luck. Goshido sounds like an amazing adventure.

Comment: [Here is a more general solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808744/how-to-find-selection-in-html-document-that-contains-iframe-or-just-frames) that also works for selected text inside of frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had hit the same problem and found your question looking for an answer myself.

The issue in your code, as far as I can tell, is not that window.getSelection is undefined in gmail, but simply that getSelection().toString() returns a zero length string despite text being selected. In Firefox Tim Down's solution worked for me but not in Chrome as contentWindow in not available.

My revised code below which iterates though any frames on the page is working in Gmail for me in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. (I've not tested it in other browsers).

```
var selectedText = '';
if (window.getSelection) { 
  selectedText = window.getSelection().toString(); 
}
if (selectedText == '') {
  var frames = window.frames; 
  for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) { 
    if (selectedText == '') { 
      selectedText = frames[i].document.getSelection().toString(); 
    }
    else { break; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great solution. As you have demonstrated programattically, you cannot rely on the text selection being in the parent _window_.

Answer (score 0):

The last case works fine for me in Gmail in Firefox. There are some flaws with that code though:

- `window.getSelection()` returns a `Selection` object, not a string (I see this everywhere. I think it's PPK's fault). You need `selectedText = "" + window.getSelection();`
- The final case covers iframes in non-IE browsers but not IE; I think (but am not certain) that `document.activeElement` in IE can point to an iframe.

Revised code:

```
var selectedText = '';
if (window.getSelection) {
  selectedText = "" + window.getSelection();
} else if (document.getSelection) {
  selectedText = document.getSelection();
} else if (document.selection) {
  selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
} else if (document.activeElement.contentWindow) {
  var win = document.activeElement.contentWindow;
  if (win.getSelection) {
    selectedText = win.getSelection();
  } else if (win.document.selection) {
    selectedText = win.document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Tim but this doesn't work for me in Gmail.

Comment: @conorwade: More details needed then, such as browser, which view in Gmail you're in and where the selection is.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using firefox 3.6 in gmail, 
A function getBrowserSelection() in the browser.js file in Firefox’s chrome is used by Firefox for the contextual menu search ..

```
var focusedWindow = document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow;
var selection = focusedWindow.getSelection();
```