# javascript: Alternative for selectionStart and selectionEnd for old versions of IE

Tags: javascript, selection

I have put together a script for grabbing a selection from a string or html in some sort of element such as as a div or span and formatting it with help from MaxArt that works great for standards-compliant browsers.  However, for older versions of IE, while I can get the selection, I don't have a way to get the start and end points.  The start and end points are necessary to put the selection, once manipulated back into the string.

SelectionStart or SelectionEnd work for textareas but not divs or spans.  The following courtesy of MaxArt works in standards-compliant browers.  Can anyone recommend something that would work in older versions of IE for span and div.

Thanks!

JS

```
function editText() {
//var sel = document.getElementById('displaytext').textContent;
//alert(sel);
    var sel = getSelection();
    alert(sel);
    var rng, startSel, endSel, sel;
if (!sel.rangeCount
        || displaytext.compareDocumentPosition((rng = sel.getRangeAt(0)).startContainer) === Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING
    || displaytext.compareDocumentPosition(rng.endContainer) === Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING ) {
    sel = "";
}
else {
    startSel = displaytext.compareDocumentPosition(rng.startContainer) === Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING ? 0 : rng.startOffset;
    endSel = displaytext.compareDocumentPosition(rng.endContainer) === Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING ? displaytext.textContent.length : rng.endOffset;
    sel = displaytext.textContent.substring(startSel, endSel);
}
}
```

HTML

```
<span id = "displaytext">HERE IS A BUNCH OF TEXT THAT I WANT TO GRAB A SELECTION FROM</span> <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="editText()">link</a>
```

Comment: cCould you describe a little more precisely what you're trying to do?

Comment: above code gives me startSel and endSel, start and end points in the form of digits respectively.  Then I can manipulate sel, for example, put <i> </i> tags around it and place it back into displaytext element with something like var len = displaytext.textContent.length;
var beg = displaytext.textContent.substring(0,startSel);
var end = displaytext.textContent.substring(endSel,len);
var whole = beg+replace+end; document.getElementById('displaytext').textContent = whole;  However this does not work in older IE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find selection in HTML document that contains iframe or just frames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808744/how-to-find-selection-in-html-document-that-contains-iframe-or-just-frames)